# Visual Studio 2017 выдает ошибку при компиляции любого проекта

Tags: c++

[image: Вот такая ошибка]

В интернете ничего толкового не нашел.

Comment: А у вас Студия нормально стала? Или вы её ставили как-то хитро?

Comment: А как вы искали, какие ключевые слова использовали?

Comment: @VladD установщик с офф сайта, проблем во время установки не было.

Comment: А операционная система какая? Вы не меняли каталог установки? Вы не ставили VS 2017 раньше на этой же машине?

Comment: [Вот есть ответ в англоязычном stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038660/visual-studio-2013-cl-exe-exited-with-code-1073741515).

Comment: @VladD, ставил раньше, точно также не работало, переустановил Windows 7 x64, полностью форматировав HDD. При установке ничего не менял..

Comment: @user: А между установкой Windows и VS вы ничего не меняли?

Comment: @VladD, нет, ничего абсолютно

Answer (score 2):

Согласно данным на сайте Microsoft, эта ошибка связана с неправильным обновлением (или отсутствием обновления) системы.

> Эта проблема возникает потому, что номер версии файла Mspdb110.dll не был правильно обновлен на момент последнего обновления.

Чтобы исправить ошибку, необходимо осуществить процесс обновления.

> Чтобы загрузить это обновление Windows Embedded Compact 2013 ежемесячно, перейдите к [Microsoft OEM Online](https://www.microsoftoem.com/) или [MyOEM](https://myoem.microsoft.com/).

После успешной загрузки и установки все должно заработать. Удачи!

**Источник:** [https://support.microsoft.com/](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/3090075/fix-error-msb6006-cl-exe-exited-with-code--1073741515-error-when-you-b)